# How can I center my <h1> when there is an <img /> next to it?

Tags: html, css, image, center, alignment

I have a problem creating a decent header in CSS. What I want is a `<h1>` header that aligns its content in the center of its parent `<div>`. Sometimes though there might be an additional logo displayed as a regular `<img />` which should be aligned to the **left**.

This is my example code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.oldfirestation.co.uk/logo_brand_example_86.jpg" />
        <h1>Not center?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
        This is the center
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #161616;
}

div.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

div.logo img {
     width: 200px;   
    float: left;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;  
    width: 50%;
}

div.more {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    clear: left;
}
```

The problem is that when I show an `<img />`, my `<h1>` text is **NOT** centered. If I remove this `<img />` it is... How can I fix it??

I have made an example on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8B9ZF/

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/8B9ZF/26/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do like this:

```
div.logo img {
     width: 200px;   
    vertical-align:middle;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;  
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/8B9ZF/8/

May be you can change your mark-up

### http://jsfiddle.net/8B9ZF/24/

Comment: This doesn't center my h1 content in the page. It centers it in the remaining space, but I want it to be centered in the entire block.

Comment: The second jsfiddle you gave actually did the trick. By using the `position: relative;` it's all fine. The `<h1>` is perfectly centered and if the `<img />` increases in height it simply pushes down the content below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make the image absolutely positioned at 0,0 instead of floating it then it won't push the H1 out of center alingment. But you then run the danger of the image overlapping the text if the image is too wide, or the container of the heading too small. To counter this, you probably want to add some padding to the left/right of the container

Comment: Yes I have thought about this too, but if the image height then increases, it grows out of my header and covers the content below: http://jsfiddle.net/8B9ZF/21/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8B9ZF/27/

this should always work as far as i know! basically this just adds overflow hidden, which makes the h1 aware of the space taken by the floated element so it takes up the remaining area!

```
body {
    background-color: #161616;
}

div.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}
div.logo{
overflow:hidden
}
div.logo img {
     width: 200px;   
    float: left;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;

    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;  

}

div.more {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: this should always work as far as i know! enjoy your coding :) basicly this just adds overflow hidden, which makes the h1 aware of the space taken by the floated element so it takes up the remaining area!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I was trying to have the `<h1>` centered in relation to the `<div class="container">` and not centered in the remaining space. Thanks for your time though.. :)

Comment: so if there is an image you want it below?